# Weird bug when using tikzexternalize + subcaption with TACL journal template

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

Minimum working example code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[]{tacl2018v2}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/,optimize command away=\includepdf]
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw] (a) {ipsum};
    \node [draw, xshift=5.5cm, yshift=1.0cm] {foo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You need the taclv2.sty file from https://transacl.org/tacl-submission-templates/tacl2018v2.sty

Resulting output:

[image]

(Just to be clear, in the tikzpicture, it is not expected to see the header 'Confidential TACL submission' added)

What I am looking for is either:

1. a way to modify my own latex code so that the header prints correctly, but my pictures are not tainted by the header, or
2. some realistic proposal for something I could send to TACL tech support that will fix the issue sustainably and cleanly.

Comment: I wouldn't use the externalize feature for papers that will be submitted.

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but it doesnt really solve my problem. I need either 1. a way to modify my own latex code so that the header prints correctly, but my pictures are not tainted by the header, or 2. some realistic proposal for something I could send to TACL tech support that will fix the issue sustainably and cleanly. Neither of the solutions presented so far match these constraints I think?

Comment: Just create the diagrams in a separate document and include it using includegraphics as usual.

Comment: I cannot imagine a scenario where you need the externalize feature when you submit a paper. Ah, and thanks for the follow-up and upvote, I appreciate it.

Comment: why has the question been closed? what additional details are required? I'm not looking for a workaround but an actual fix. Many papers do work ok with externalize, but not this particular template. How could the template be modified to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

### It's Not A Bug -- It's A Feature

- My understanding is, that the `tacl2018v2` package has a hard-coded output routine that adds the string `Confidential TACL submission. DO NOT DISTRIBUTE.` to the output. It uses `\AddToShipoutPicture` which I assume is a so-called "hook" that is originally from the `eso-pic` package. The style file also mentions (line 208):

> Based on eso-pic.sty

- Since `\tikzexternalize` compiles the document it also generates the hard-coded string. The details can be found in **Chapter 52.4 Externalizing Graphics** of the manual.
- You can modify the style file for `tacl2018v2` as shown below.

[image]

### Problematic Code (Hard-Coded Output Routine)

```
% Hard-coded output routine, just FYI (line 348 ff.).
\def\leftoffset{-2.1cm} %original: -45pt
\def\rightoffset{17.5cm} %original: 500pt
\iftaclpubformat\else\pagenumbering{arabic}\fi
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\iftaclpubformat\else
\AtPageLowishCenter{\thepage}
\aclruleroffset=\textheight
\advance\aclruleroffset4pt
  \AtTextUpperLeft{%
    \put(\LenToUnit{\leftoffset},\LenToUnit{-\aclruleroffset}){%left ruler
      \aclruler{\aclrulercount}}
    \put(\LenToUnit{\rightoffset},\LenToUnit{-\aclruleroffset}){%right ruler
      \aclruler{\aclrulercount}}
  }
  \AtTextUpperLeft{%confidential
    \put(0,\LenToUnit{1cm}){\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering\naaclhv\confidential}} % <-- Problematic part
  }
\fi
}
```

### Solution 1

```
% Change this in tacl2018v2.sty, line 337 ff.
\def\confidentialtext{Confidential TACL submission. DO NOT DISTRIBUTE.}
%\def\confidential{\confidentialtext} % <-- Old
\def\confidential{} % <-- New
```

I modified the style file and called it `tacl2018v2_modified.sty`. **Make sure** you delete the generated `main-figure0.pdf` (or similar), otherwise it will not be re-generated.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tacl2018v2_modified} % <-- I renamed the style file.

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw] (a) {ipsum};
    \node [draw, xshift=5.5cm, yshift=1.0cm] {foo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Solution 2

Or just override the problematic command (`\def\confidential{}`) after the package is loaded.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tacl2018v2}
% Override the evil command :). AFTER loading tacl2018v2.
\def\confidential{}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw] (a) {ipsum};
    \node [draw, xshift=5.5cm, yshift=1.0cm] {foo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```